# Phantomjs and ajax

Tags: phantomjs

I am a total noob with phantomjs, and I don't do any web development.
However, I want to get phantomjs to sit on my page, like a browser.

When a browser does this, I see a call every few seconds (5?). It appears to be an ajax thing.

When I load the page with phantomjs, it loads successfully, but I never see the call that is made as if I am in a browser.

Hopefully, this is not a difficult thing. Since I do not have any experience I don't want to have to jump through a bunch of hoops to make it work!

Thanks!

My very basic code is such:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://myurl.com/', function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
    // Do other things here...
 });
```

Comment: Please add the code you use and, if possible, URL to test against (recommended).

Comment: See it where? How would you see an ajax call in a headless browser?

Comment: @Vaviloff Posted my code, I assume "do other things here", would just have just been doing browser things.

Comment: @pguardiario My web server logs of course. Where else would I see the call?

Comment: Well there's hooks like `page.onResourceReceived` where you can print them to console.

Comment: jgauthier, you really think this basic example can help? I'm amazed by some of the posters here. You've come for help and you dont provide any useful concrete information. Do you even want to get help?

Comment: Use page.onError callback to check for any error when opening page in PhantomJS. Maje a screenshot to check if it works at all. Cant suggest anything else unless you share more about the site.

Comment: What part of "I'm a noob" was confusing to you?  I've NEVER used phantomjs, and I was hoping to put together a small, and quick script to open a web page and sit on it, just like my browser does.  I discovered quickly, it doesn't act like a browser.   I've told you exactly what my skill level is with this, and what I've tried to do.  If this is an advanced technique, then I'll move on and do something I'm familiar with.

Comment: jgauthier, judging by your question you seem well knowledgeable about what you're doing, which is why I ask for clarification of the question. In theory PhantomJS is able to do what you're after, which means something is wrong with implementation of your script and/or target HTML page. Absence of both is anything but helpful.